# Using Uber with unusually large luggage (ski bag)

Tags: luggage, uber

I will be traveling solo in a major US city with luggage including a set of skis in a travel bag. This bag is almost 2 meters long. Many cars can accommodate it, but not all.

How do I let the driver know ahead of time that I have such a bag, or otherwise ensure that we can make this work?

Comment: See https://thehobbykraze.com/competitive/skiing/ski-bag-in-uber/

Comment: I travel with a ski bag that's 190cm long and never had a problem. What kind of cars can't fit your skis with one of the seats folded?

Comment: The best bet to be certain that it fits is Uber Van if it is available but yeah, 90% of cars will be able to fit it in